# How do I completely remove Unity Next?

Tags: software-installation

I followed [the instructions](http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unitynext/) to install Unity Next. They worked, and I was able to run Unity Next.

Here are the instructions I used (quoting from the above link, with parts removed):

> ```
> $ mkdir ~/unity
> ```
>
> **Fetch Unity Next source**
>
> ```
> $ sudo apt-get install bzr
> $ bzr branch lp:unity/phablet ~/unity/unity-next
> $ cd ~/unity/unity-next
> ```
>
> **Download & dependencies**
>
> ```
> $ ./build -s
> ```
>
> this will:
>
> - Add ppa:phablet-team/desktop-deps, ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper, ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team
> - Build and install lp:libunity/phablet, lp:unity/phablet-mods, lp:hud/phablet and lp:unity-lens-people locally
> - Install build dependencies
>
> **Build UnityNext**
>
> ```
> $ ./build
> ```
>
> **Run UnityNext**
>
> ```
> $ cd ~/unity/unity-next
> $ ./run
> ```

However, later when I tried to build a KDE application, I ran into a bunch of errors. The only thing that I think this could be is because of the Unity Next installation, so I would like to remove it. However, I can't find any instructions on how to remove it, either on the aforementioned page or using Google.

It appears that it installed some dependencies and a PPA, but I don't know how to easily remove them all and undo all the changes the installation did.

**How do I completely remove Unity Next, including all its dependencies and extra PPAs?**

Comment: so you built it from source?

Comment: @strugee Yes, I built it from source by following the directions in the article mentioned. It installed a bunch of additional Debian package dependencies and a PPA, plus some extra code from launchpad. I'm using Ubuntu 13.04, since that matters.

Comment: i've come back to this question, sorry i was gone :)
how exactly did you run Unity Next? i'm talking terminal commands used to launch it. also, i've added more build dependencies that i've discovered in the build script.

Comment: @strugee I simply followed the exact instructions in the link. Should I add them to my question? I ended up getting Unity Next removed by using your original answer with more dependencies (so I'm not sure if your added dependencies are enough). Thanks for your help, sorry I forgot to mark it as excepted right away.

Comment: no problem. if you could put the instructions in the question, that'd be lovely (for future visitors). having not done this myself, basically what you did is you ran executables directly from the directory where they were built?

Comment: also, if you found some more build dependencies that i haven't seen yet, you can always edit my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of `ppa-purge` and reinstallation. Disclaimer: I have not tested this in any way possibly imaginable.

### Step 1: Preparation

First install the `ppa-purge` tool: `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge` or click here: [ppa-purge [image: Install ppa-purge]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ppa-purge)

### Step 2: Remove software

Now run:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:phablet-team/desktop-deps
sudo ppa-purge ppa:phablet-team/desktop-deps
```

If you're not on Raring, additionally run:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
```

This will remove the PPAs from your system, which basically means removing them from your software sources, and resetting the packages to the default versions from the official repos. See the [manpage for the `ppa-purge` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ppa-purge) for more info on how it works.

Note that while the phablet-team/desktop-deps PPA is not mentioned in the compilation guide, it is mentioned in the build script.

Next you need to remove the final binaries that you compiled. Based on your description of how you ran the software, you should be able to just run `rm -rf /path/to/build/directory` where `/path/to/build/directory` is the directory in which you built Unity Next. I think this is the directory that you would have run `./build` from. If you followed the instructions without changing any paths, this directory should be `~/unity`.

### Step 3 (optional): remove build dependencies

Note: while these commands are written in such a way as to not uninstall any software that you don't want to be uninstalled, they will automatically remove any packages that you don't need on your system (packages installed to satisfy a dependency, but not needed anymore because nothing installed depends on them). This is a completely safe result, but be aware of what is happening.

If you want to get rid of build dependencies, and are running Raring:

```
sudo apt-mark auto qt-components-ubuntu qtdeclarative5-dee-plugin indicators-client indicators-client-plugin-* qtbase5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev-tools qtdeclarative5-test-plugin libdee-qt5-dev libpulse-dev qtdeclarative5-xmllistmodel-plugin unity-lens-mock demo-assets libboost-regex1.49-dev ubuntu-mobile
# this next command may or may not work in Raring. let me know in a comment.
sudo apt-mark auto bamfdaemon debhelper dh-autoreconf gir1.2-dee-1.0 gnome-common gnome-doc-utils gobject-introspection gtk-doc-tools indicator-application indicator-appmenu indicator-appmenu-tools intltool libappindicator3-dev libbamf3-dev libdbusmenu-glib-dev libdbusmenu-gtk3-dev libdbusmenu-jsonloader-dev libdbustest1-dev libdee-dev libgirepository1.0-dev libgtk-3-dev libncurses5-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev metacity sqlite3 valac-0.18 libpocketsphinx-dev libsphinxbase-dev
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

If you want to get rid of build dependencies, and are running Quantal or lower:

```
sudo apt-mark auto qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin qtdeclarative5-dee-plugin indicators-client indicators-client-plugin-* qtbase5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev-tools qtdeclarative5-test-plugin libdee-qt5-dev libpulse-dev qtdeclarative5-xmllistmodel-plugin unity-lens-mock demo-assets libboost-regex1.49-dev ubuntu-mobile
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

The guide also has you install `bzr`: if you really don't want that on your system, run `sudo apt-get remove bzr`. It doesn't really matter though, since it's not a huge package.